# Biblatex using prefix for selected keywords only

Tags: biblatex

I am trying to generate a numbered list of publications where some publications should be highlighted by using an "S" prefix, such as [S1]. The other publications should be normal. So far I have been unsuccessful in achieving this using BibLateX as I can only get the highlighted papers in the bibliography list.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=numeric,backend=biber]{biblatex} 
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{art2,
author={John Doe and Jane Roe},
journal={Journal of Teamwork},
title={Some title},
year={2007},
month={Dec},
volume={11},
number={8}
}
@ARTICLE{art3,
author={John Doe},
journal={Some Journal},
title={A great paper},
year={2009},
month={Jan},
volume={45},
number={1},
keywords={first}
}
@ARTICLE{art3,
author={Jane Roe},
journal={Journal of Articles},
title={An Article by Jane},
year={2010},
month={Feb},
volume={46},
number={2}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\assignrefcontextkeyws[labelprefix=S]{keyword=first}
\assignrefcontextkeyws[labelprefix={}]{notkeyword=first}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[keyword=first,notkeyword=first,heading=none]
\end{document}
```

And I would like this code to produce something like this:

```
 [1] John Doe and Jane Roe, "Some title", Journal of teamwork 11 (2007).
[S2] John Doe, "A great paper", Some Journal 45 (2009).
 [3] Jane Roe, "An article by Jane", Journal of Articles 46 (2010).
```

Comment: So you are OK with the numbering ignoring the 'S'?

Comment: Yes I am. In fact, that is required.

Comment: Good. Then that should be possible even without refcontexts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to mark up some special entries with a certain keyword with the additional "S", but not split them out over different bibliography lists, it's probably easiest to just inject the marker into the `labelnumber` format as needed.

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{%
  \ifkeyword{first}{S}{}%
  #1}
```

You won't need any `\assignrefcontextkeyws`. (The correct syntax would have been `\assignrefcontextkeyws[labelprefix=S]{first}` and there is no `notkeyword` version.)

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=numeric,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{%
  \ifkeyword{first}{S}{}%
  #1}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{art2,
  author={John Doe and Jane Roe},
  journal={Journal of Teamwork},
  title={Some title},
  year={2007},
  month={Dec},
  volume={11},
  number={8},
}
@ARTICLE{art1,
  author={John Doe},
  journal={Some Journal},
  title={A great paper},
  year={2009},
  month={Jan},
  volume={45},
  number={1},
  keywords={first},
}
@ARTICLE{art3,
  author={Jane Roe},
  journal={Journal of Articles},
  title={An Article by Jane},
  year={2010},
  month={Feb},
  volume={46},
  number={2},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{art1} \cite{art2} \cite{art3}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: gives S1 2 3]

Comment: Using this with the 'nature' style results in `Macro 'cite' undefined`. Any idea?

Comment: @Liris `nature` is based on a different style with more complex definitions. If you need help getting this to work, I suggest you ask a new question. This is too complex for the comment section.

Comment: If someone is looking for this, [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/699680/customization-of-the-numeric-comp-style-in-biblatex) is most of the solution

Comment: In your solution, you can see that the numbers are left aligned, causing the start of the references S marked to be slightly misaligned with the others. How can I get the [S1] to be right aligned with [2] ?

Comment: @Liris Good catch. I updated the answer with an alternative method that is more elegant in this case and does not mess up the alignment. (It won't necessarily play well with styles based on `numeric-comp`, though, so it will only get you so far.)

Comment: It works with `numeric-comp` as soon as it does not need to compact citations mixing the two keywords, so that's perfect for me !