# Problem with prefix for selected citations and biblatex styles

Tags: biblatex

As described in the question [Biblatex using prefix for selected keywords only](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/383202/biblatex-using-prefix-for-selected-keywords-only), I need to highlight some references with a prefix, e.g., [A2]. Following the answer to the above question, I was able to get the desired result. However, when I apply a specific biblatex-style, the prefix in front of the \cite key disappears. The bibliography itself is not affected.
Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[
    backend = biber,
    sorting = none,
    %style = ieee
]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}{references.bib}
@ARTICLE{art1,
author={John Doe and Jane Roe},
journal={Journal of Teamwork},
title={Some title},
year={2007},
}
@ARTICLE{art2,
author={John Doe},
journal={Some Journal},
title={A great paper},
year={2009},
}
@ARTICLE{art3,
author={Jane Roe},
journal={Journal of Articles},
title={An Article by Jane},
year={2010},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{catA}
\addtocategory{catA}{art2}
\addbibresource{references.bib}


\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
    \printfield{labelprefix}%
    \ifcategory{catA}{A.}{}%
    \printfield{labelnumber}%
    \ifbool{bbx:subentry}
      {\printfield{entrysetcount}}
      {}}}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
      \printfield{labelprefix}%
      \ifcategory{catA}{A.}{}%
      \printfield{labelnumber}}}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelnumberwidth}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}


\begin{document}
    \cite{art1}, \cite{art2}, \cite{art3}
    \printbibliography[heading = none]
\end{document}
```

As desired, the output is

[image]

but after uncommenting the line

```
style = ieee
```

the output becomes

[image]

The same happens for other styles as well.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: The IEEE style uses a compressed citation style, so that e.g. [1,2,3] will appear as [1]-[3] so the plain `cite` bibmacro is not used, instead the `cite:comp` (plus `cite:comp:comp` among others) is. So the compressed numeric citation macros are substantially more complex.  But this raises the question of how you would like that compression to occur when it contains one of your special categories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the IEEE style uses the `numeric-comp` numbering style underlying, a simple change to the `cite` bibmacro doesn't work, which is why you see the labels disappear when you change the style.  The numeric-comp macros need to keep track of the starting and ending citation number, so there are more of them that need to be modified. The following is lightly tested, but it seems like it does what you are looking for. One of the `biblatex` developers is active on the site, so before accepting this answer, you may want to wait until they give it their blessing (or explain what's wrong with it.)  You can play around with other orders of the citations to see that it also deals with the last number correctly as well.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[
    backend = biber,
    sorting = none,
    style = ieee
]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{art1,
author={John Doe and Jane Roe},
journal={Journal of Teamwork},
title={Some title},
year={2007},
}
@ARTICLE{art2,
author={John Doe},
journal={Some Journal},
title={A great paper},
year={2009},
}
@ARTICLE{art3,
author={Jane Roe},
journal={Journal of Articles},
title={An Article by Jane},
year={2010},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{catA}
\addtocategory{catA}{art2}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:print:labelnumber}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
    \printfield{labelprefix}%
    \ifcategory{catA}{A.}{}%
    \printfield{labelnumber}}}
    
\makeatletter 
\renewbibmacro*{cite:print:last:labelnumber}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref:lastkey]{%
    \ifdef\cbx@lastprefix
      {\printtext[labelprefix]{\cbx@lastprefix}}
      {}%
    \ifcategory{catA}{A.}{}%
    \printtext[labelnumber]{\cbx@lastnumber}}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:print:last:subentry:comp}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref:lastkey]{%
    \printtext[entrysetcount]{\cbx@lastentrysetcount}}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:print:last:labelnumber}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref:lastkey]{%
    \ifdef\cbx@lastprefix
      {\printtext[labelprefix]{\cbx@lastprefix}}
      {}%
      \ifcategory{catA}{A.}{}%
    \printtext[labelnumber]{\cbx@lastnumber}}}
\makeatother

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
      \printfield{labelprefix}%
      \ifcategory{catA}{A.}{}%
      \printfield{labelnumber}}}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelnumberwidth}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}


\begin{document}

\cite{art1,art2,art3}
    
 \cite{art1,art2}
    
    \cite{art1} \cite{art2}
    \printbibliography[heading = none]
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]